# repeat awk and if statement for all columns

Tags: loops, if-statement, awk

I have a file of more than 50 columns and I would like to output only fields with last character equals to 1 in all columns. How do loop the if statement shown below for all columns?

```
awk '{if(substr($0,length($0),1) == 1) print $0}' file_with_one_column.tsv
```

extra info:
(1) delimiter: tab
(2) output format: same number of columns as input (excluding fields with last character != 1). i.e not one line ouput
(3) same number of lines in all columns
(4) issue: some fields contain only '.' charachter.

I'm getting this issue when I tried to use for loop
`awk: 1: unexpected character '.'`

Example input:

```
ENSG00000267601.1    ENSG00000256861.1    ENSG00000259953.2
DGCR8_H_2_2          .                    SAFB2_K_1_2
IGF2BP3_H_1_1        DDX6_K_1_2           LIN28B_H_1_2
NKRF_H_2_2           PPIL4_K_2_2          LIN28B_K_1_1
IGF2BP1_H_2_2        CDC40_H_1_2          LIN28B_K_2_1
POLR2G_H_2_2         IGF2BP3_H_1_2        .
```

Desired output:

```
ENSG00000267601.1    ENSG00000256861.1    ENSG00000259953.2
IGF2BP3_H_1_1                             LIN28B_K_1_1
                                          LIN28B_K_2_1
```

Comment: Which answer did you try? The one I have below works just fine

Comment: I tried all suggestions but getting error (awk: 1: unexpected character '.'). Your suggestion only worked on column 1, but not the rest of the columns

Comment: _I'm getting this issue when I tried to use for loop_ How did you try to use the `for` loop? That looks like an error you might get when you are trying to execute the data with awk.

Comment: There's something about the way you're calling awk that you haven't shared with us yet (e.g. maybe you're storing it in a variable and then trying to use it or calling it from python or from DOS or something) because there's nothing in that script that would generate that error if it were just called from shell as written. If you're calling it from a shell script then the bug is somewhere else in your shell script, maybe a missing quote or something somewhere before the call to awk. Copy/paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see if it finds any errors.

Comment: If you still can't figure it out after that then create a minimal, complete shell script (assuming you are working with a shell script) that produces the error and post that in your question so we can help you debug it.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I figured that I was calling the awk function the wrong way. But after correcting the way to call awk function, I still dont get the output that I want. The awk function only worked on the first column but not the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(substr($i,length($i),1)=="1") print $i}}' file.tsv
```

This prints every field on a separate line.

If you want to filter the lines and only print those columns which end with 1 you may use:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{
    found = 0
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(substr($i,length($i),1) == "1") {
            printf "%s%s", (found?OFS:""), $i
            found = 1
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        printf "%s", ORS
    }
}' file.tsv
```

Btw, unless your input file is really large, I would call the check `substr($i,length($i),1) == "1"` micro-optimization and replace it by the more readable regular expression `$i ~ /1$/`

Comment: Some of my columns only contain "." character. I'm getting this errror: awk: 1: unexpected character '.'

Comment: @Jan then you copy/pasted wrong or there's something about the way you're calling awk that you haven't shared with us yet because there's nothing in that script that would generate that error if it were just called from shell as written.

Comment: I have tried with the newest suggestion and I am getting the desired result. Thank you @hek2mgl